# Tagged PDF XML Schema

Tags: pdf

I want to convert the XML generated from tagged PDF (Acrobat --> Save as XML 1.0) into Html. I did review the "tagged pdf" section in the PDF reference version 1.7. I'm wondering if there is already an XSL stylesheet to to this conversion or there is an XML schema reference for the tagged pdf.